# Map WP Multisite blog.example.com to anotherdomain.com/blog?

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I have a WordPress Multisite installation at `blog.example.com`. I wish to serve it on `somedomain.com/blog`, I wish to know if this is possible.

I'm aware of mapping `blog.example.com` to `somedomain.com` or`abc.somedomain.com`. I have Caddy server powering the WP multisite.

Let me know how do I go about solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up Caddy to reverse proxy requests to the Multisite installation:

In your Caddyfile, add a reverse_proxy directive for the Multisite:

```
somedomain.com/blog {
    reverse_proxy blog.example.com
}
```

This will forward all requests to `somedomain.com/blog` to the Multisite installation at `blog.example.com.`

Next, update the WordPress Multisite configuration to use the new domain:

In your WordPress database, go to the `wp_blogs` table and locate the row for your main site (usually with `blog_id` of 1).

Change the domain and path values to `somedomain.com` and `/blog`, respectively.

Also update the siteurl and home values in the `wp_options` table to `https://somedomain.com/blog.`

steps required depending on your specific setup, such as updating permalinks, changing any hard-coded links in your content, and configuring SSL certificates.

Comment: Do I need to setup reverse proxy on the multisite installation OR the target domain?